# Why do I keep getting not defined error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, embed, vimeo-player

I have an example with Vimeo player API. I have installed through npm the video player api. When I call it and use some JavaScript to communicate with the API I get this error: `Line 15: 'Vimeo' is not defined`

I am importing in the vimeo folder from the node modules. Here is what I have:

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react';
     import axios from 'axios';
     import player from '@vimeo/player';


           var options = {
               id: 28028960,
               width: 640,
               loop: false
           };

           var player = new Vimeo.Player('mainPlayer', options);

           player.setVolume(0);

           player.on('play', function() {
              console.log('played the video!');
        });
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: So where did you import `Vimeo`?

Comment: You aren't declaring `Vimeo` anywhere. I suspect your `var player = new Vimeo.Player('mainPlayer', options);` should be `var = new player(...);`.

Comment: check doc https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#using-with-a-module-bundler

Comment: Hi @ArupRakshit vimeo should be imported through `import player from @vimeo/player` that's where the api is.

Comment: Checked the link I gave?

Comment: @ArupRakshit i just saw it thanks

Comment: @ArupRakshit I followed the example and it gave me a new error: `TypeError: You must pass either a valid element or a valid id.`